# How to generate report from sqlite database in cordova phonegap?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

How can I generate daily, Weekly, Monthly reports from sqlite database in cordova phonegap? I can not getting data between two dates. 
I am applying query 
"SELECT * FROM sales where saledate <=1-1-2015 AND saledate >=1-1-2016"
where saledate column type is DATE.

Comment: If you check your query there are not any date that match conditions

Comment: try wrapping dates between double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with BETWEEN it works better

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE saledate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01';
```

Also, your query is not ok, you are selecting the dates which are not in the interval. Also use 01 for days and months with only one character, and try using this notation (YYYY-MM-DD)